# How to treat PosgreSQL array fields in QGIS rule-based styles filters

Tags: qgis, postgresql, symbology, array, rule-based

In a PostgreSQL/PostGIS DB I have a table with an attribute declared as a 1-dimensional integer array `INTEGER[]` holding a value like `{1,2,3,4,5}`. Now I would like to build a rule-based style and need to test if a certain value is in the array. I'm not quite sure if I have to treat it as text and test for substring like (let's say test for 3 is in the array)

```
`strpos("myattribute", '{3,')) > 0 or strpos("myattribute", ',3,')) > 0 or strpos("myattribute", ',3}')) > 0`
```

or if it is treated as some sort of list and I may use

```
`3 in "myattribute"`
```

giving an invalid expression. Can it be converted to a list in some way or is my text approach recommended?

Answer (score 2):

I tried this using the [sal_emp example](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/arrays.html) on the postgres website - no spatial data in this example, but it does include an integer array

```
CREATE TABLE sal_emp (
    name            text,
    pay_by_quarter  integer[],
    schedule        text[][]
);

INSERT INTO sal_emp
    VALUES ('Bill',
    '{10000, 10000, 12000, 13000}',
    '{{"meeting", "lunch"}, {"training", "presentation"}}');

INSERT INTO sal_emp
    VALUES ('Carol',
    '{20000, 25000, 25000, 25000}',
    '{{"breakfast", "consulting"}, {"meeting", "lunch"}}');
```

I tried loading the layer in the usual way (using the add Postgresql layer icon) and looking at the table it appears to be of type text (or rather, QString)

However, you could (if the number of discrete values is low enough) create some views (or import separate layers) using **DB Manager** and its SQL editor.For example the query

```
SELECT * FROM "sal_emp" WHERE "sal_emp"."pay_by_quarter" @> ARRAY[20000]
```

will list all rows where 20000 appears in the pay_by_quarter field. You can either create a view, or add it as a new layer, then style it appropriately.

**@>** is an "array contains" operator. You could also use

```
SELECT * FROM "sal_emp" WHERE 20000 = ANY (pay_by_quarter);
```

Or, you can duplicate the layer and apply a similar query using the **Filter** functionality, which will pass through the query to the underlying Postgres driver...

[image]